# VBScript - Capitalize first letter of each word

Tags: string, vbscript, capitalize

I am trying to convert the following string `james-and-the-giant-peach` to the following: `James and the Giant Peach` so basically swapping - for a space, and capitalizing the first letter of each word except words like and, the, or etc.

I have tried a few examples and can do a simple replace to get rid of - for a space, but I am struggling to convert every starting letter of each word to uppercase.

Here is code used before this and the code to call the function itself: 
`strModpack = Replace(Modpack,"-"," ") strModpack = MakeUpperCase ( strModpack )`

Here is the code I tried to start with:

```
Function MakeUpperCase ( inputText )
  Dim arrWords, x, curWord
  Dim leftPart, rightPart
  arrWords = Split(inputText, " ")
    For x=0 To UBound(arrWords)
      curWord = arrWords(x)
    If Len(curWord)>0 Then
        leftPart = UCase(Left(curWord, 1))
        If Len(curWord)>1 Then
            rightPart = LCase(Right(curWord, Len(curWord) - 1))
        Else  
            rightPart = ""
        End If
        curWord = leftPart & rightPart

    End If
    arrWords(x) = curWord
    Next
       MakeUpperCase = Join(arrWords, " ")
    Erase arrWords
End Function
```

My output is currently: `James and the giant peach`

EDIT: The below code seemed to be so close, but only does one of the words it needs to lowercase.

```
Function MakeUpperCase(inputText)

Dim arrWords, x, curWord
Dim leftPart, rightPart

Exclude = "and,the"
arrExclude = Split ( Exclude, "," )
arrWords = Split ( inputText, " " )

 For x=0 To UBound(arrWords)
  curWord = arrWords(x)
   If Len(curWord)>0 Then
      leftPart = UCase(Left(curWord, 1))
   If Len(curWord)>1 Then
       rightPart = LCase(Right(curWord, Len(curWord) - 1))
    If curWord = arrExclude(intWord) Then           
        leftPart = LCase(leftPart)
    End if
    Else  
       rightPart = ""
   End If
 curWord = leftPart & rightPart

End If
arrWords(x) = curWord
Next
   MakeUpperCase = Join(arrWords, " ")
Erase arrWords

End Function
```

Output currently now is: James and The Giant Peach (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current output is not "James and the giant peach" if you're really using `arrWords = Split(inputText, " ")` - that has to be changed to "-" delimiter - for your example input anyways.

Then it comes back to `James And The Giant Peach`

In any case - I think this slight modification should work for you.

> **FINAL VERSION**

```
 '  CONVERT TO UPPERCASE FUNCTION ------------------------ '
 Function MakeUpperCase(inputText)

  Dim arrWords, x, curWord
  Dim leftPart, rightPart

Exclude = "of,the"
arrExclude = Split ( Exclude, "," )
arrWords = Split ( inputText, " " )

 For x=0 To UBound(arrWords)
curWord = arrWords(x)
If Len(curWord)>0 Then
   leftPart = UCase(Left(curWord, 1))

        If Len(curWord)>1 Then
            rightPart = LCase(Right(curWord, Len(curWord) - 1))

            For intWord = 0 to UBound(arrExclude)
                If curWord = arrExclude(intWord) Then           
                    leftPart = LCase(leftPart)
                end if
            Next
        Else  
           rightPart = ""
        End If

        curWord = leftPart & rightPart

    End If
    arrWords(x) = curWord
Next

MakeUpperCase = Join(arrWords, " ")
Erase arrWords

End Function
```

Comment: I was using `strModpack = Replace(Modpack,"-"," ")` elsewhere in the code, but then realised `strModpack = MakeUpperCase ( Modpack )`was wrong, it was meant to be `strModpack = MakeUpperCase ( strModpack )` I have now corrected that and have the proper case, now just to include code to check against the words NOT to capitalize.

Comment: If the code in your question is not what you're using you should edit it and make a note of it for us - have you tried the code above?

Comment: Using the above code gives me Error for an expected = on the line for `Const EXCLUDE_WORDS As String = "the,a,and,or,was,is"`

Comment: Ahh - vbscript doesn't need to declare constants like VBA . Just change that to a 'Dim string` - I'll update the code

Comment: Ahh, please see the updated code when the edit gets approved, I tinkered based on what you put in, almost got it, it only changes one of the words I want to lowercase from arrExclude.

Comment: I have made a final edit of my initial post, please see the updated code I am using.

Comment: Not sure why my post got edited with your answer??? Your answer is not looping thru the excluded words. You're just comparing against the first value in the array (intWord=0). You need ot either loop thru all excluded words - or use Instr to search for value in the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118757/discussion-between-bolte-and-dbmitch).

Comment: Expected end of statement on line `next intWord`

Comment: Never mind I fixed it, had to change the loop slightly. `    For intWord = 0 to UBound(arrExclude)
                 If curWord = arrExclude(intWord) Then           
                     leftPart = LCase(leftPart)
                    end if
                Next
` I basically removed exit for and intWord from next.

Comment: Excellent - it didn't like `Exit For`?

Comment: Added the final edit to your post, it now works brilliantly... I messed up a second ago, re-check now, I had to just remove exit for and intword from the next statement.

Comment: Okay - possible that vbscript doesn't like naming the next counter - it should allow you to exit for though - that saves a few string checks when it does find a match

Comment: When I exit for at the location you suggested, it cuts the loop off, only dropping uppercase from one of the words set to exclude. Without ending the loop with exit for, it works as expected, it seems the next itself ends the loop from what I can tell..

Answer (score 0):

Using the right tools

1. string replace for "-" => " "
2. RegExp with replace function for Caps
3. dictionary for exceptions

you'll get:

```
Option Explicit

' replace function for 'words', heads, and tails
Function rf(sm, g1, g2, g3, np, ss)
  If Not gdLowers.Exists(g1) Then g1 = UCase(g2) & g3
  rf = g1
End Function

Dim s
' dictionary to hold words that stay lower case
Dim gdLowers : Set gdLowers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each s In Split("a the and")
    gdLowers(s) = Empty
Next

Dim f : Set f = GetRef("rf")
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Pattern = "\b((.)(.*?))\b"
Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
    "james-and-the-giant-peach" _
  , "add-some-of-your-own" _
)

For Each s In aTests
    WScript.Echo s
    WScript.Echo r.Replace(Replace(s, "-", " "), f)
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 38686250.vbs
james-and-the-giant-peach
James and the Giant Peach

add-some-of-your-own
Add Some Of Your Own
```

and the insight that you need a grammar for **proper** capitals.